# Estimate (noun) in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

Can I say, “the numbers below are estimates?” or “the numbers below are estimated figure?” What is the better way saying?

Comment: "The numbers below are estimates," is fine. Adding "figure" is not necessary, and if it were, it should be plural.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "the numbers below are estimates" is clear. Since numbers and figures are synonymous, the "figure(s)" in the second phrase doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gorlux, "the numbers below are estimates" is all that is required to communicate the intended meaning. However, even though the second phrase is incorrect as written, it could read: "the numbers below are an estimate" or "the numbers below are estimated figures" and substitute the first phrase.